# How to assign result to a variable AND print result in one command in Python?

Tags: python, r

In `R`, when you assign something to a variable, you can wrap your code in brackets to also print the result:

```
> a<-1+2
> a
3

>(a<-1+2)
3
```

Is there an equivalent feature in python?

Comment: This only works in R because `(` and `<-` are actually functions. Both have return values, but `<-` returns invisibly.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't mix statements and expressions in the same "command".

You can, however, use `;` to have both on the same "line":

```
a = 1 ; print(a)
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *single statement* which allows to that.

First we have [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt). Which allow to, well, make assignments.

And then you have either a [`print` **function**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) (for Python 3.x) or a [`print` **statement**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) (for Python 2.x). But neither of them cannot be mixed with the aforementioned assignemnt statement.

So no, you cannot do that in a single statement. You can, of couse, cheat that into one line by using `;` but that is something not very readable which I would not recommend.

---

#### Bonun non-aswering rambling

From a readability point of view, assigning and printing are two very different things which should not be mixed.

Moreover, if you are (for instance) using a logging library instead of direct `print` usage, then the "single statement" you are looking for would become useless. In fact, I think that that is a rationale behind moving `print` from statement to function.

So, you don't have a single statement for assign-and-print and, I will add, that kind of statement doesn't seem a good idea in the Python language.